# Does DNS RFC allow record separated by dot if no specific subdomain exists?

Tags: subdomain, rfc1035

Let say I have a DNS domain `example.org.` with a **subdomain** `sub.example.org.` declared on my DNS servers.

Per RFC, am I allowed to create a record `foo.bar.sub.example.org.` even if the **subdomain** `bar.sub.example.org.` is not explicitly declared ?

My tests with commercial products such as [EfficientIP DNS](https://efficientip.com/) shows that it allows that kind of record.

If this is allowed, how should I interpret the `foo.bar.sub.example.org.` ? Is this a record `foo.bar.` in the subdomain `sub.example.org.` ?

I'm struggling to find a real answer to this question that is not that easy to formulate.

Thanks. Regards

Comment: According to the RFC for domains (RFC1035) the only requirement to be a domain is to follow the syntax defined in section 2.3.1. Why would the DNS system require all parent domains to be registered? What's your assumption, why and what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Hi @fredrik . I'm not trying to achieve anything here. Just a question I'm usually asking myself when creating DNS records. Just to understand correctly, in my example above, entry `foo.bar.sub.example.org.`  should be understood as record `foo.bar.` in the subdomain `sub.example.org.` ?

Comment: That would depend on the server implementation. Purely from a domain perspective, it's the `foo` subdomain in the `bar` subdomain of the `sub` subdomain of the `example` domain in the `org` TLD.